# Tikz: Cutting parts of the top and bottom line of a node of type rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, block

I am trying to cut the bottom and top line of a standard rectangle. What I have now, is a rectangle that looks like:

[image: Tikz rectangle with text inside]

Which was the result of:
`\node [rectangle,draw=black,rounded corners=30pt,dashed]  {Test123};`

My desired result would be something like that:

[image]

I somehow can not believe there is no better solution, than painting over the top and bottom line with another white line (which would additionally get very messy with more rectangles, like in my case).

It would be great if the solution would have the following properties:

1. text can easily be embedded/added/attached
2. lines can be drawn from/to anchor of that object
3. can easily be moved (as a whole object)

As I am not an tikz pro, I apologize if the aforementioned properties are standard features for drawing/objects in tikz.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option using a style and `append after command` to add the dashed lines to the node; since the solution uses `\path ... node ...;` you can do all operations on nodes (use the standard available keys, name them and have access to their anchors to draw elements):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  keep name/.style={
    prefix after command={
      \pgfextra{\let\fixname\tikzlastnode}
    }
  },
  partialbox/.style={
    keep name,
    append after command={
  ([xshift=#1]\fixname.north west) -- 
  (\fixname.north west) -- 
  (\fixname.south west) -- 
  ([xshift=#1]\fixname.south west)
  ([xshift=-#1]\fixname.north east) -- 
  (\fixname.north east) -- 
  (\fixname.south east) -- 
  ([xshift=-#1]\fixname.south east)
    }
  },
  partialbox/.default=15pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[draw,rounded corners,dashed]
 node[partialbox,minimum height=30pt,align=center]
  {Some test text};
\path[draw,rounded corners=20pt,dashed]
 node[partialbox,minimum height=50pt,align=center,fill=red!20]
   at (4,0)
   (A)
  {Some test text};
\path[draw,rounded corners=20pt,dashed]
 node[partialbox=30pt,minimum height=70pt,fill=cyan!20]
   at (8,0)
   (B)
  {Some test text};
\path[draw,rounded corners=20pt,dotted]
 node[partialbox,minimum height=70pt]
   at (0,-4)
  {Some test text};
\path[draw=red!80!black,line width=1pt,rounded corners=20pt,densely dashed]
 node[partialbox=20pt,minimum height=40pt,align=center,inner sep=20pt]
   at (4,-4)
   (C)
  {Some  \\ additional test text \\ and some more};
\draw[-latex]
  (A.south) -- ++(0pt,-25pt) -| (B.south);
\draw[latex-latex]
  (B.east) -- ++(10pt,0pt) |- (C.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, which does exactly what I wanted it to. Providing extensive use cases with different parameters makes it even more than I was hoping for!